# \x not working inside the substitution

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I'm trying to decode the unicode characters. So I simply tried the hexadecimal escape sequence `\x{}` inside the regex substitution `e`

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $k = get("url");

my ($kv) =map{/js_call\(\\"(.+?)\\"\)/} $k;

#now $kv data is https://someurl/call.pl?id=15967737\u0026locale=en-GB\u0026mkhun=ccce

$kv=~s/\\u(.{4})/"\x{$1}"/eg;
```

I'm trying substitute the all unicode character.

My expected output is:

```
https://someurl/call.pl?id=15967737&locale=en-GB&mkhun=ccce
```

Below mentioned `print` statement gives the expected output. However the regex seems doesn't working properly.

```
print "\x{0026}";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with `s/\\u(.{4})/"\x{$1}"/e` is that the backslash escape `\x{$1}` is evaluated at compile time, which gives a NULL byte:

```
$ perl -E 'printf "%vX\n", "\x{$1}"'
0
```

If we escape the backslash in front of `x` ( `s/\\u(.{4})/"\\x{$1}"/ge` ) we get a string with literal escape sequences, but still not the desired unicode character:

```
use feature qw(say);
$kv = '\u0026';
$kv =~ s/\\u(.{4})/"\\x{$1}"/ge;
say $kv;
```

The output is now:

```
\x{0026}
```

With a small modification, you can produce `"\x{0026}"` instead, which is Perl code you can compile and execute to produce the desired value. To do this, you need involve `eval(EXPR)`.

```
$kv =~ s/\\u(.{4})/ my $s = eval(qq{"\\x{$1}"}); die $@ if $@; $s /ge;
```

This can be shortened to

```
$kv =~ s/\\u(.{4})/ qq{"\\x{$1}"} /gee;
```

Howver, a far better solution is to use the following:

```
$kv =~ s/\\u(.{4})/chr hex $1/ge;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you enable `use warnings` you'll see that the `$1` gets evaluated literally before the backreference gets interpolated.

```
$kv =~ s/\\u(.{4})/ sprintf("\"\\x{%s}\"", $1) /eeg;
```

sort of works, but it is hideously ugly.  I've been trying to simplify it, but the various ideas I tried always got me back to "Illegal hexadecimal digit '$' ignored" warnings.

Answer (score 2):

May be this also you can try:

`$kv=~s/\\u([[:xdigit:]]{1,5})/chr(eval("0x$1"))/egis;`

Thanks.