# How to convert a literal string to its represented unicode in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, string-literals

If I have a literal string like

```
my $x = 'JPMorgan Chase \x{0026} Co';
```

I would like to convert it to

```
"JPMorgan Chase \x{0026} Co"
```

which contains a unicode in it.  (Please note the difference between the double and single quotes.)

What is the easiest way to do this?  This is a simplified example.  The actual problem has many such instances.

Comment: `$x = eval qq{"$x"}` ?

Comment: This works indeed.  Thx!

Comment: See also [\x not working inside the substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39992351/2173773)

Answer (score 4):

If the only escape format you need to handle is `\x{1234}`, then one way of handling this might be to match the escape sequence with a regular expression, then use `chr(hex($1))` to convert a hexadecimal string to a character:

```
my $x = 'JPMorgan Chase \x{0026} Co';
$x =~ s/\\x\{([0-9a-f]+)\}/chr(hex($1))/e;
say $x; # -> "JPMorgan Chase & Co"
```

Comment: This also works.  Didn't know about /e flag before.  Thanks.

Comment: Probably needs to handle `\\ ` too, at the very least.

Comment: @ikegami I mean, depends on what the input actually is. The question only mentioned the `\x{1234}` syntax, so…

Comment: Exactly. The question is probably (or even surely) missing something, and therefore so is the answer, so care should be taken.

Answer (score 2):

While duskwuff & mob do a fine job answering your direct question.  (FWIW: mob's `$x = eval qq{"$x"}` has an undeniable elegance to it.)  The real question is why you have Perl character escapes someplace other than in an interpolating string?  If you are getting this string from someplace *other* than your source code (IO), and a raw unicode encoding is inappropreate, consider a more common encoding for which Perl has readily available modules:

- URI encoding: `%26`
- XML encoding: `&#x26`
- JSON encoding: `\u0026`

...and many others.  Such encodings will make your IPC and data files far more inter-operable with other systems.

... and or course, if these things *are* in your Perl source, just put 'em in double quotes and let the compiler phase interpolate them.